# Passing local variable to a global function

Tags: c#, .net

In my program i am passing a locally constructed variable to a  global class object's member function. The member function will assign this variable to a private member and use it through out the program. Is there any drawback in this approach?

```
public void function()
{
int a = 0;
globalClassObject.StoreValue(a);

}
```

Comment: Whats the question here?

Comment: @Jason the question is if there is any drawback by doing that

Comment: What is a `global class object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine. The problem would be if you would pass a reference to this variable. In this case the value is "copied" to the variable within the function so the original `a` variable isn't actually used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with this. The variable is used in local scope only, so no unexpected results here.

Answer (score -1):

The big drawback is if this value can be changed anywhere else in the program. If it can, your program will become a swamp for bugs to breed. If the globalClassObject stores the value immutably, there is no problem.